Issues due to Directory Scanning in Hadoop 3.4.0
We have recently upgraded from Hadoop 3.3.5 to 3.4.0. After this upgrade we see that Directory Scanning is running every 6 hours and during this scan we observed that some of the hdfs file append/write operations are failed.
We see below exceptions in datanode
2024-06-20 08:03:22,878 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Block:1076796450 is not a regular file.
2024-06-20 08:03:22,878 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Reporting the block blk_1076796450_37259760 as corrupt due to length mismatch
2024-06-20 08:03:22,878 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Metadata file in memory /hadoop/dfs/data/current/BP-1675987674-172.29.2.253-1697438894786/current/finalized/subdir14/subdir28/blk_1076796451_37259775.meta does not match file found by scan null
2024-06-20 08:03:22,878 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl: Block:1076796451 is not a regular file.

We see below exceptions in namenode
2024-06-20 08:23:40,064 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* NameSystem.append: append: lastBlock=blk_1076796432_37259771 of src=/DATA/ds=20240620/tsp=023000/neidp=5/data.avro is not sufficiently replicated yet.

Then when we reduced the Directory Scan interval to 2 hours , these issues are not appearing
My questions are:

Is this Directory Scan mandatory for Hadoop Normal Operations. Can we disable this by setting the interval value to -1?
Is it OK to reduce the interval to 2 hours? What are the impacts?
What is the maximum allowed limit for this interval?

We are periodically writing Hadoop files and we expect it to work normally during Directory Scanning
